# How to display messages from the database on left and right?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, mysqli, pdo

'I made a simple chat box with php but the problem is i want to display my messages on the right and the other user messages on the left i made two while loops but they didn't work. My table is like this
(Sender - reciever - msg)
I want to display each message ordered by time and on different places right side and left side

```
if (isset($_POST['user_id'])){
  $sender_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages_sys WHERE send_id=$sender_id AND reciever_id=$uid";
  $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  print_r($sql_query);
```

Comment: Please add your code so far.

Comment: Can you show me the Sender and Receiver table columns

Comment: ive addded the code look at it and tell me what do u think i still haven't done anything yet that works so i left it there at mysqli queri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'if' statement inside for loop :

```
foreach($messages as $message){

   if($message->reciever == user_id){
     <div class="right">$message</div>

   }elseif($meesage->sender == user_id){
    <div class="left">$message</div>

   }

}
```

of course you have to open and close php tag before type html code inside

Comment: make sure you added "right" and "left"  classes in css style

Comment: i already done that it still doesnt work look at the code in my question please

Comment: perfect, it worked. i guess i gotta learn more about sql, any tutorials u k ?